# Save contents of Flash file to hard drive?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am creating a custom banner creator app and it has the ability to add images/text and move them around and I was wondering what is the best way to allow the user to somehow 'save' the banner to their My Documents folder so that they can then later load it back in again and move the text/images around if they want to?

Comment: First thing you need to know is that you can only achieve this in an AIR application.

Comment: @Marty All I have been told to do is add "Save/load features (so the user can save mockups to their 'My Documents' folder and load in previous designs)

Comment: Yes, what I mean is that accessing the users' file system is only possible in an AIR Application, not from a SWF.

Comment: Ah, I have to do it in AS3 / Flash CS6 and compile it as an .exe file

Comment: Unfortunately exporting to an exe won't allow you to do what you want to do.

Comment: It is possible to open local files and save to local file system from the Flash Player plugin in a browser, although with some limitations. See for example http://pixlr.com/editor/

Comment: @Marty Not exactly, you can do at least `FileReference.save()` and `FileReference.load()` to use external files.

Comment: @user3238047 You cannot directly save an SWF, while you can save a metadata of the banner. For this, you can use a file of either XML or JSON format, with images encoded as PNG or JPG and then converted to strings in base64 encoding so that they won't mess up the XML/JSON format. Of course, you will have to parse that metadata back on load.